# OpenGL FreeType: weird texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, freetype

After I have initialized the library and loaded the texture I get http://postimg.org/image/4tzkq4uhl.

But when I added this line to the texture code:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(w * h, 0);
```

I get http://postimg.org/image/kqycmumvt.

Why is this happening when I add that specific code, and why does it seems like the letter is multiplied? I have searched examples and tutorials about FreeType and I saw that in some of them they change the buffer array, but I didn't really understand that, so if you can explain that to me, I may handle this better.

Texture Load:

```
Texture::Texture(FT_GlyphSlot slot) {
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    int w = slot->bitmap.width;
    int h = slot->bitmap.rows;

    // When I remove this line, the black rectangle below the letter reappears.
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(w * h, 0);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, slot->bitmap.buffer);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 uv;
in vec4 tColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

out vec4 color;

void main () {
    color = vec4(tColor.rgb, texture(tex, uv).a);
}
```

Comment: You are setting texture wrapping to repeat, and you are asking why the texture repeats?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It does that even if I change GL_REPEAT, and if it is supposed to repeat then why it repeats like that?

Comment: Wait... this line of code is completely irrelevant to what you're doing with your textures. You're doing something else.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That is the reason why it is so weird. I change only that line and the texture changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` for the format of the data you pass to `glTexImage2D()`. Based on the corresponding FreeType documentation I found here:

http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Pixel_Mode

There is no `FT_Pixel_Mode` value specifying that the data in `slot->bitmap.buffer` is in fact luminance-alpha. `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` is a format with 2 bytes per pixel, where the first byte is used for R, G, and B when the data is used to specify a RGBA image, and the second byte is used for A.

Based on the data you're showing, `slot->bitmap.pixel_mode` is most likely `FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY`, which means that the bitmap data is 1 byte per pixel. In this case, you need to use `GL_ALPHA` for the format:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows, 0,
             GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, slot->bitmap.buffer);
```

If the `pixel_mode` is something other than `FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY`, you'll have to adjust the format accordingly, or potentially create a copy of the data if it's a format that is not supported by `glTexImage2D()`.

The reason you get garbage if you specify `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` instead of `GL_ALPHA` is that it reads twice as much data as is contained in the data you pass in. The content of the data that is read beyond the allocated bitmap data is undefined, and may well change depending on what other variables you declare/allocate.

If you want to use texture formats that are still supported in the core profile instead of the deprecated `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` or `GL_ALPHA`, you can use `GL_R8` instead. Since this format has only one component, instead of the four in `GL_RGBA`, this will also use 75% less texture memory:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, slot->bitmap.width, slot->bitmap.rows, 0,
             GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, slot->bitmap.buffer);
```

This will also require a slight change in the shader to read the `r` component instead of the `a` component:

```
color = vec4(tColor.rgb, texture(tex, uv).r);
```

Comment: You are correct but isn't GL_ALPHA deprecated? Anyway, I posted what I did to fix the problem.

Comment: Your question was why the problem was happening, and I didn't see that explained in your answer. Yes, `GL_ALPHA` is deprecated, together with `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`. Since you used that in your code, I suggested the closest relative. If you want to use modern formats, something like `GL_R8` would be a lot more efficient, using only 25% of the space you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I added the following to my code and it works good.

```
GLubyte * data = new GLubyte[2 * w * h];

    for( int y = 0; y < slot->bitmap.rows; y++ )
    {

        for( int x = 0; x < slot->bitmap.width; x++ )
        {

            data[2 * ( x + y * w )] = 255;
            data[2 * ( x + y * w ) + 1] = slot->bitmap.buffer[x + slot->bitmap.width * y];

        }

    }
```

I don't know what happened with that particular line I added but now it works.